How to get visualization working on Windows Media Player 10 installed in wine
After some trying I've got the mp3 playback working perfectly on Windows Media Player 10 installed on wine using Playonlinux. The wine version I used for this is 9.0-rc5.
Here are the steps:

Create wineprefix WMP10.
Install Windows Media Player 10 by winetricks wmp10.
Download and acquire the following four dlls: devenum.dll, jscript.dll, quartz.dll, and urlmon.dll.
Copy over and replace these dlls to c:\windows\system32 folder.
Run regsvr32 devenum.dll regsvr32 jscript.dll regsvr32 quartz.dll regsvr32 urlmon.dll to register them.
In winecfg add overrides for devenum, jscript, quartz, and urlmon and set to Native then Builtin. This is to tell wine to use the replaced dlls that were copied over.

Now if you execute the program by running wmplayer.exe, the mp3 playback should work.
My question now, is how do I get visualization to work as well. Thank you for your help in advance.
